# dplyr merge rows and combine column where all columns except one match

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that looks like the following:

```
ID  Val1 Val2 Val3
0     2    3    4
1     5    3    2
2     3    4    3
3     4    5    9
3     2    5    9
```

All values will match except for Val1 so I am looking to merge rows where there is duplicate ID's and combine there differing values from Val1. My expected output would be:

```
ID  Val1 Val2 Val3
0     2    3    4
1     5    3    2
2     3    4    3
3    4,2   5    9
```

The `aggregate` function seems to be close but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Row 3 then would be a string, not a number. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes that would be fine I am just going to be counting the occurrences of the values so a string will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'ID' and summarise the other columns by taking the `unique` value of theme and wrapping in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise_all(~ list(unique(.)))
```

---

Or if we need a single string, can `paste` the `unique` elements

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_all(~ toString(unique(.)))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     ID Val1  Val2  Val3 
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     0 2     3     4    
#2     1 5     3     2    
#3     2 3     4     3    
#4     3 4, 2  5     9
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, I) # creates list column
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, toString) # creates string
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Val1 = c(2L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 2L), Val2 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), Val3 = c(4L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 
9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```